# git filter-branch error: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'

Tags: git

I want to move all codes generated on folder `oldFolder\` to `newFolder\`, and there are **hundreds of files** in `oldFolder\` from **hundreds of past git commits**, so when doing that, i want to make sure my **git commit history looks nice and clean**, i.e. if we look at commit history it seems like all those file were created or edited on `newFolder` since the very beginning.

Because of that i choose `git filter-branch`.

However, when i run following command:

> git filter-branch --tree-filter "mv src\com\myweb\oldFolder\
>   src\com\myweb\newFolder\" HEAD

It gave me an **error**

> Rewrite 28db94b1bad4f3f787551e521053f38a48284971 (1/586) (0 seconds
>   passed, remaining 0 predicted)
>
> C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64/libexec/git-core\git-filter-branch: eval:
>   line 401: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
>
> C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64/libexec/git-core\git-filter-branch: eval:
>   line 402: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Why is this happening? and how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

The slash at the end of the command has escaped the double quote character.

Try:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter "mv src\com\myweb\oldFolder src\com\myweb\newFolder" HEAD
```

Or use `/` instead.